# radio button won't work when minimized

Tags: disabled-control, minimized

My radio won't work whenever I resize it smaller but works smoothly whenever I full screen it. Can anyone tell why I cannot select the radio buttons when the windows is smaller?

Comment: Please elaborate your issue and add your code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Going from full screen to desktop, well thereis a big difference in how windows handels events. For instance, when minimized windows OS has to handle other windows and if windows are on top of windows, if your actions cause a loop with out threading, usually you want to do that in a background worker, you will lockup the application. There is no way to know what your particular issue is without seeing code.

Comment: I figured it out! there's a div that's blocking the radio button when the screen was resized smaller. Thank you